# Trouble with install redmine-hudson plugin on bitnami redmine 1.4.1

Tags: rubygems, redmine, redmine-plugins, pg

everyone.

I tried to install redmine-hudson plugin(1.0.8) on bitnami redmine 1.4.1.

I just follow the installation guide down here.

```
>Installing a plugin
>
>1. Copy your plugin directory into #{RAILS_ROOT}/vendor/plugins. If you are downloading the plugin directly from GitHub, you can do so by changing into your plugin directory and issuing a command like git clone git://github.com/user_name/name_of_the_plugin.git.
>
>2. If the plugin requires a migration, run the following command to upgrade your database (make a db backup before):
>>rake db:migrate_plugins RAILS_ENV=production
>
>3. Restart Redmine
>
>You should now be able to see the plugin list in Administration -> Plugins and configure the newly installed plugin (if the plugin requires to be configured).
```

when I execute "rake", it shows me an error like this.

```
>[root@localhost ~]# rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
> 
>Some gems may need to be installed or updated.
> 
>Please run 'bundle install --without development test'.
```

and then....

```
>[root@localhost redmine]# bundle install --without development test
>
>Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
>
>Using activesupport (2.3.14) 
>
>Using rack (1.1.3) 
>
>Using actionpack (2.3.14) 
>
>Using actionmailer (2.3.14) 
>
>Using activerecord (2.3.14) 
>
>Using activeresource (2.3.14) 
>
>Using cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0) 
>
>Using coderay (1.0.6) 
>
>Using daemons (1.0.10) 
>
>Using fastercsv (1.5.4) 
>
>Using fastthread (1.0.7) 
>
>Using gem_plugin (0.2.3) 
>
>Using i18n (0.4.2) 
>
>Using mongrel (1.1.5) 
>
>Using mysql (2.8.1) 
>
>Using net-ldap (0.3.1) 
>
>Installing pg (0.13.2) with native extensions
>
>Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
> 
>> /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
> 
>checking for pg_config... yes 
>
>Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config 
>
>checking for libpq-fe.h... yes 
>
>checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes 
>
>checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
>
>checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... yes 
>
>checking for PQconnectionUsedPassword()... no 
>
>Your PostgreSQL is too old. Either install an older version of this gem or upgrade your database.
> 
>*** extconf.rb failed ***
> 
>Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
> 
>necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details. You may need configuration options.
> 
>Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/pg-0.13.2 for inspection. 
>
>Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/pg-0.13.2/ext/gem_make.out
>
>An error occured while installing pg (0.13.2), and Bundler cannot continue. 
>
>Make sure that 'gem install pg -v '0.13.2'' succeeds before bundling.
>
```

so, i tried to install 'pg' using gem. but...!

```
>[root@localhost redmine]# gem install pg -v '0.13.2'
> 
>Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
> 
>ERROR:  Error installing pg:
> 
>>ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>>
>>/usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
> 
>checking for pg_config... yes 
>
>Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config 
>
>checking for libpq-fe.h... yes 
>
>checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes 
>
>checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
>
>checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... yes 
>
>checking for PQconnectionUsedPassword()... no
> 
>Your PostgreSQL is too old. Either install an older version of this gem or upgrade your database.
> 
>*** extconf.rb failed ***
> 
>Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  
>
>Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.
```

after this, I couldn't figure it out how to setup.

anyone knows about this problem?

Bitnami Redmine package has Redmine(1.4.1), RubyGem(1.3.6), Ruby(1.8.7), Rails(2.3.5).

And these are installed on CentOS 5.5.

without redmine-hudson plugin, redmine, hudson are working normally.

what am i have to do to use it?

Answer (score -2):

Uh, the error output says:

```
Your PostgreSQL is too old. Either install an older version of this gem 
or upgrade your database.
```

You'll need to follow that advice.